# How to set page navigation as always bottom of the Grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

[image: RK]

This is my web page Grid view.If i'm add so many records it will put automatically page navigation,the page navigation numbers will comes under the records.(i'm rounded in red color)

if the grid view has three records in second page means the page navigation numbers comes middle of the grid view.but i need to show under the grid view records.The grid view has default 10 rows.

the first page have 10 records so there it's working fine. how to do second page and above upcoming pages.

Does any one know how to solve this problem...?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Am i the only one that doesn't understand your problem? The pager by default is always below the GridView records as shown in your screenshot independently of the number of records on that page. Could you clarify your issue?

Comment: I think that what is meant is : for a 10 Rows gridview (10 rows "height" wanted) , if there's only 3 records, the pagination comes right after the rows, instead of "showing 7 empty rows". This could be achieve by defining a "min height" for the view before the pagination.

Comment: Thank u guys... i find the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PagerSettings.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.position.aspx):

```
 <asp:gridview id="CustomerGridView"
      datasourceid="CustomerDataSource"
      autogeneratecolumns="true"
      datakeynames="CustomerID"  
      allowpaging="true"
      runat="server">

      <pagersettings mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"
        firstpagetext="First"
        lastpagetext="Last"
        nextpagetext="Next"
        previouspagetext="Prev"   
        position="Bottom"/> 

    </asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think adding the `empty` rows to the `dataSource` (depends upon rows and pagesize) would be better option.